# Explain this behaviour of scala class

Tags: scala, class, object

I was wondering about this behaviour of scala class which is shown in the code snippet. The execution of following code prints `hi` , my confusion is what goes on in the background that without any method and field definition the invocation of TestClass executes the **bare** code? Also why is such kind of bare code writing within a class is allowed ?

```
class TestClass {

  if(true)
    println("hi")
}

object TestObject extends App{
  val ci = new TestClass
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special syntax of 'bare' code inside classes is Scala's equivalent of Java's initializers / anonymous constructors that use braces around the code. Both initializers in Java and the code in your Scala class are executed on object creation, which is what you do inside your `TestObject` when calling the `TestClass` constructor with `new`.

Comment: No, it's the equivalent of normal Java constructors.

Answer (score 3):

The body of a class, object or trait (except for method definitions) is its (primary) constructor. It's more complicated for classes and object extending [`DelayedInit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/index.html#scala.DelayedInit) (or `App`, which extends `DelayedInit`).

Comment: I was going to add that what happens to the App code is even weirder.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the use of `App`.

Comment: Can you also explain why keeping `val x = println(2+2)` in the class body will execute the RHS when invoking `new TestClass`

Comment: Because initialization of `val`s is also done in the constructor.